# WEKA's "Class has to be nominal if cost matrix given" error

Tags: machine-learning, runtime-error, classification, weka

I am trying to classify a data with 51 features with the command

> DecisionTable -X 1 -S "weka.attributeSelection.GreedyStepwise -T -1.79 -N -1 -num-slots 1"

but I am getting the error

[image]

**What does this error mean about nominal class for cost matrix?**

Comment: you could run the Discretize Filter your "class attribute" (the last/lowermost one in the table), and/ or apply the "NumericToNominal" Filter before running the classifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [knb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/202553/knb), you can solve this problem by changing the non-nominal values to Nominal. You can use `Multifilter` to have many filters.

- You can find the Remove filter in the Multifilter under `Filters > Unsupervised > Attribute > Remove`.
- You can find the NumericToNomial `Filters > Unsupervised > Attribute > NumericToNomial`

*Example showing Multifilter with Remove Filter and NumericToNomial*

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Its hard to tell you the exact reason without seeing your data.
But "class has to be nominal" tells you that you need a nominal label.

example for binary label   : {0,1}

example for nominal label  : {very, small, middle, big, very big}

example for continous label: real numbers

you need to classify your data nominal (or binary) with the given costmatrix

Comment: Can you give some examples about what are not nominal? So is this issue some ARFF file problem? I autogenerated the ARFF file from CSV in WEKA.

Comment: not nominal would be all numbers between 1 and 2. could be 0.1! could be 0.57239472347239847239847234983274987239! So its continous. In other words. The number of possible results is infinite. a finite possibility of answers would be nominal

Comment: It is not clear in the answer or comment but you are trying to say that continous values and decimals are not nominal?

Comment: Yeah, i just reread my comment and i wrote that a bit unclear. Just read it on wiki ;-)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_and_discrete_variable